# Extract integers from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find some integers from a string. And store them in a list.

Here is my example strings:

> --- +++ @@ **-8**,7 **+8**,7 @@  identified track: "10" System check @@ **-17**,7 **+17**,7 @@ Quit the server with  @@ **-31**,7 **+31**,7 @@ Starting development : 526 server at ---@@ **-41**,7 **+41**,7 @@ file changes with StatReloader

The integers which I want to extract will be in from of @@ -X,7 +X,7 @@ where X is the integer that is to be extracted.

So the output will be :

```
[8, 17, 31, 41]
```

Comment: Seems like you need regex (regular expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """--- +++ @@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ identified track: "10" System check @@ -17,7 +17,7 @@ Quit the server with @@ -31,7 +31,7 @@ Starting development : 526 server at ---@@ -41,7 +41,7 @@ file changes with StatReloader"""
print(re.findall(r"@@ -(\d+)", s))
# --> ['8', '17', '31', '41']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user regular expressions for this:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'(\d+),')
```

In case if you don't need duplicates:

```
result = set(result)
```

Read more about Python re module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
print(re.findall(r"(\-\d+)|(\+\d+)", "[string you want]"))
```

> **Change** `[string you want]` to your string...